# mvc5 attribute routing within area can't find view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-areas, attributerouting

When I'm inside `Admin` area and map my routes using attribute routing it cannot find view because it doesn't look inside actual area view folders but instead only global view folders.

Only if I pass full path to view it then can display it, otherwise it throws me error.

**Error**

```
The view 'Authorize' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Home/Authorize.aspx
~/Views/Home/Authorize.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Authorize.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Authorize.ascx
~/Views/Home/Authorize.cshtml
~/Views/Home/Authorize.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Authorize.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Authorize.vbhtml
```

**Code**

```
[RoutePrefix("admin")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    [Route]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View("Authorize"); // Error
        return View("~/Areas/Admin/Views/Home/Authorize.cshtml"); // Working
    }
}
```

Note that if I disable attribute routing and switch back to good old routes it will work. Any way of fixing this or it's working as intended and I should apply full path in all my areas?

Comment: May help some http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22436573/default-area-cant-find-view

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to add the `[RouteArea("")]` attribute to your controller:

```
[RouteArea("Admin")]
public class HomeController : Controller
```

You can find the documentation [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx#route-areas).

Comment: Strangely this gives `HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found` on the Index action.

Comment: Found what's causing it. When you use `RouteArea` you should remove `RoutePrefix`.

Comment: You can also include a prefix (different than the area name) like this [RouteArea("Admin", AreaPrefix = "myprefix")]

Comment: Just `[RouteArea]` was enough for me